# Extracting key value pair with regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I am trying to get key value pairs from a string like this

`TestKeyAAA: Hello World TestKeyBBB: 987654321 TestKeyCCC: A long sentence with a date time in it 2016-09-29T20:15:11 some more text TestKeyDDD: 123456789`

And want to receive paires like this

`TestKeyAAA = „Hello World“
TestKeyBBB = „987654321“
TestKeyCCC = „A long sentence with a date time in it 2016-09-29T20:15:11 some more text“
TestKeyDDD = „123456789“`

The pattern I am using is this

`(.+?):(.+?)(?=(?:[^\s]+:)|(?:$))`

It works good, except for the value of key TestKeyCCC. The problem is the „:“ in the date.

The keys only contain `[A-Z],[a-z],. and /`

I tried it with the following pattern

`([A-Za-z\.]+?):(.+?)(?=(?:[^\s]+:)|(?:$))`

But this didn't work to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The keys don‘t contain spaces and numbers. They contain the chars A-Z,a-z,“.“,“/“. Here are some examples „Location“, „C/F“, „Num.“

Comment: you can throw in those special quotes in the character range of the Regex, seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to exclude digits as well as whitespaces when matching for ":"

```
([A-Za-z\.]+?):(.+?)(?=(?:[^\s0-9]+:)|(?:$))
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work with your test scenario.

```
(?<key>[A-Za-z\.,/]+?):\s(?<value>.+?)(?=\s[A-Za-z\.,/]+?:|$)
```

Comment: edited to account for all your key characters as specified in question